# Format string with variable in HEX format

Tags: c#

I know I can include variables into string:

```
int a =1
String s = $"a={a}";
```

This will show line:

```
a=1
```

But how to show answer in HEX format as below?

```
a=0x01
```

Comment: `String s = $"a=0x{a:X2}";`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1;
string s = $"a=0x{a:x2}";
```